# problem in windows powershell while installing haskell

Tags: windows, powershell, haskell, ghci

I try to install haskell in my windows machine, I followed the instructions given in the website of haskell.org, but when I execute in the powerShell as an administrator this commande:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; try { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/sh/bootstrap-haskell.ps1 -UseBasicParsing))) -ArgumentList $true } catch { Write-Error $_ }
```

It doesn't work and the terminal prints this message when the installation begins:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; try { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock
([ScriptBlock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/sh/bootstrap-haskell.ps1 -UseBasicParsing)))
-ArgumentList $true } catch { Write-Error $_ } : Exec: Error executing command curl.exe with arguments '-o
C:\Users\MBI\AppData\Local\Temp\\msys2-base-x86_64-20221216.sfx.exe
https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/x86_64/msys2-base-x86_64-20221216.sfx.exe'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

can you help me I don't know what is the problem

Comment: You have an extra backslash : C:\Users\MBI\AppData\Local\Temp\\msys2-base-x86_64-20221216.sfx.exe

Comment: and how can I fix it? I am just executing the command that i copied from the website of haskell

Comment: You can download the ps1 by putting following into a browser URL : `https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/sh/bootstrap-haskell.ps1`  Then find where extra backslash is being generated.

Comment: Looks like haskell people are pretty bad at powershell.

Comment: Haskell has a native [Windows installer](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/), so that might work better?

Comment: I think a double backslash does not make the comand to fail. Probably has to do with permissions. Do your computer has remote script executing persmission? I remember someone has that problem